# Data-binding and php error

Tags: php, data-binding, knockout.js

Hi this is what I'm trying to do.

What I'm trying to do is if the data-bind id() is equal to 1 or 2 hide it , but show all the others.

```
 <?php if($authUser->Plan=='3'){ ?>
        <div class="image-item" data-bind="visible: id() == 1,2, css:{hide}" data-bind="css:{active: ($parent.theme()==id())}">
    <?php } ?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php if($authUser->Plan=='3'){ ?>
        <div class="image-item" data-bind="visible: ('simple'==id()) || ('amelia'==id()), css:{active: ($parent.theme()==id())}">
    <?php } ?>
```